# C++ Could somebody help me explain a map/for_each code [EDIT]

Tags: c++, foreach, map-function

[Thank you for the answers, and also sorry for not really understanding all, I guess I'm trying to run yet know know how to walk]
If somebody could explain me what happens here, I would really appriciate it!
(Just learning C++ and I couldn't really understand by myself/Mr.Google)

```
string luck;
int choice;
std::map< int, std::string > cookies {
{ 1, "Tomorrow is a day" },
{ 2, "Tomorrow can be cool" },
{ 3, "Summer is coming" }
};
while( cookies.size() ) {
cout << "What cookie do you want? [";
for_each( cookies.begin(), cookies.end(), []( std::map< int, string >::value_type & v ) { cout << v.first << ','; } );
cout << ']';
cin >> choice;

map< int, string >::iterator iter( cookies.find( choice ) );
if( iter == cookies.end() )
    cout << "Sorry, that cookie has been taken" << endl;
else {
    cout << iter->second << endl;
    cookies.erase( iter );
}
```

If possible, please try to explain it to me like you're explaining how to walk to a child, I really only know the basics of the basic.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you could use a good primer to C++, from a book perhaps. There are even some free ones. Try C++ Annotations.

Comment: Here is some good books list : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Too many unrelated questions. Break them up and be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

The `#include <ctime>` is unneeded in the code you have posted. Removing it would have no effect.

The `#include <algorithm>` is needed for the `std::for_each`.
The `std::` prefix is not needed as some of the arguments are also in the `std` namespace.

`std::for_each` is a function that calls the functor given as the third argument on each element between the given begin and end iterators.

`[]( std::map< int, string >::value_type & v ) { cout << v.first << ','; }` is a lambda function used as the above mentioned functor.

The `for_each` block is maybe easier to understand written as a range based for loop:

```
for(auto v: cookies)
{
    cout << v.first << ',';
}
```

Comment: It is interesting to note that this ugly `using namespace std;` is not required for `for_each`, thanks to ADL.

Comment: Good point, thanks @Quentin

Answer (score 1):

1. `#include <map>` you need for using standart stl map container more info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)
2. the same for header `<algorithm>` it's allow you to use algorithm for_each more info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)
3. Atually I don't know for what header `<ctime>` needed here but you can read about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/)
4. [fore_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

> `template <class InputIterator, class Function>
>      Function for_each (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn);`
>
> Applies function fn to each of the elements in the range [first,last).

And also more info you also can find in different books